# Closure Compiler: How to compile Chrome extension popup with background reference

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-closure-compiler

I am writing a Chrome extension with `background.js` and `popup.js` scripts.

In `background.js`:

```
function foo(){
  // Does something
}
```

In `popup.js`:

```
var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
backgroundPage.foo();
```

Compiling these two files separate will, of course, break the `backgroundPage.foo()` reference, because `foo` gets renamed differently in `background.js` and `popup.js`.

I know the "correct" way to fix this would be to export `foo` in `background.js` using `window["foo"] = foo;`, but I would like to avoid exports if possible (to make the code as unreadable as possible).

I've tried compiling both scripts in one run and splitting them into seperate output files using `--module`:

```
java -jar compiler.jar
  --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS--js background.js popup.js
  --module backgroundMin:1
  --module popupMin:1:backgroundMin
```

Not surprisingly this doesn't work, because the compiler doesn't know that `backgroundPage` in `popup.js` is the same as `window` in `background.js`. I tried annotating using `@lends`, `@borrows` and `@memberOf`, but haven't been able to get it to work.

So my question is: Is it possible to compile both `background.js` and `popup.js` so `foo()` gets renamed - without exporting `foo()` and without breaking the reference from `popup.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `--module` option is probably the best path - I can't think of a better one.

To get renaming to work correctly, you should be able to extend the Window type:

```
/** @extends {Window} */
function MyWindow () {}

MyWindow.prototype = window.prototype;

/** @return {void} */
MyWindow.prototype.foo = function() {};
```

Then in background.js

```
var backgroundPage =
    /** @type {MyWindow} */ (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage());
backgroundPage.foo();
```

The type cast should work here because `MyWindow` extended `Window`.

All of this would be placed in your actual code. Don't use an extern or that will block renaming.

Comment: I assume you mean the first code block goes into `background.js` and the second code block into `popup.js`, right? I see the idea, but the compiler decides it can just move `foo()` inside `popupMin.ks`, which doesn't work because `foo()` can contain references to other variables in `background.js` (and won't be callable from `background.js` either). Maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: In `background.js` you would have to have: `var myWindow = new MyWindow(); myWindow.foo();` The compiler won't move the code if it is used within both modules, but you must reference the function consistently.

Comment: What if `foo()` is never actually called in `background.js` (and shouldn't be), but has to be in `background.js` due to dependencies on other functions? If you've got `background.js` and `popup.js` script files that give you the expected output after compiling, I appreciate if you could edit them into your answer.

Comment: If you want to edit your question to include at least a minimalist reproduction case and post the compiler options you are using, I can try to take a look.

Comment: The reason I asked for a complete example was because you code doesn't work for me - I figured out it was just a matter of capitalizing `Window` in `Window.prototype`, however. I've resorted to using exports instead though, because only function names will be preserved - globals will need to have get/set functions defined, so it's not really elegant regardless of using your solution or exports. I'll probably look into variable maps at a later time.